# sharepoint sandboxed solution make ajax post call

Tags: sandbox-solution, ajax

I have created a sandboxed solution for SharePoint 2010 which contains sandboxed visual webpart. I need to make ajax POST call and pass the entities from javascript. can you tell me how can I accomplish this requirement? How can we load the .aspx page and where will I write the code behind so that I can get the variables passed using ajax POST?

```
$.ajax({
 url: "https://mydomain.com/Sandbox/webservice/page.aspx",
  beforeSend: function (xhr){
         xhr.setRequestHeader('command', 'name');
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(){var x=something}
          timeout: 5000
    });
```

Now my question is how can i load the aspx page and how can i access the entities like "command" from code behind?

Answer (score 1):

You put your ajax call in a separate javascript function that takes your parameters as arguments:

```
function myFunction(command, name){
    ...
}
```

Then you can call it from your web part by printing out the html to call the function with your arguments passed in. In a standard web part I did it myself like this:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter html)
{
    ...
    html.Write(string.Format("<script>ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {{ myfunction('{0}','{1}') }}, 'sp.js');</script>", myCommand, myName)));
}
```

You could accomplish the same with a literalcontrol if you don't use the RenderContents method.

Comment: Do you have a working sample of the same? actually I am trying to pass the data from javascript(client) to server side using ajax call (POST) method.. The solution which you have told seems to be different from the requierment. Email ID: sharmila.k88@gmail.com

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood; from your first post I thought you wanted to pass a variable from your web part to your javascript. You actually want to do the opposite?

Comment: Yes. i need to pass variables from javascript to server side using ajax call

Answer (score 0):

hi if you are using ajax control tool kit make sure that tool kit is compactable with the SP2010 if its compactable then your ajax codes will work.
you can open a visual webpart and add your ajax codes and deploy it into your SP2010 site. then add the webpart.